# How to Roll back Sharepoint content editor

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have content editor on my team site where I added several links. But today while adding some new links, content editor crashed. so now when I tried to open site containing content editor, browser stop working.

The quick solution is: 
I can delete the existing content editor and create a new one (using `?contents=1` in the corrupted team site). But since my content editor contains lot of links, so is there a way where I can roll back content editor to previous version (till yesterday afternoon)?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I flagged this topic to be moved to SharePoint.StackExchange.com. You will get much better responses there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous version is probably lost in the mess. You will have to go to the site admin, and close / delete the webpart and start over. You may be able to simply close the web part (from site admin) and then edit the web part properties to salvage it's contents.

Either way, content should not be added directly into a Content Editor Web Part (for this reason.) Instead, use the option to point to a file in a Document Library elsewhere in your SharePoint site, with versioning enabled.

Then, in the case of the CEWP blowing up the page from an edit to the contents, you can revert to the previous version of the document, and the CEWP will immediately be updated, and the page immediately restored.

Comment: @Rohita-Khatiwada If this Q and A disappears, it has moved to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com Be sure to create an account over there, they have saved my SharePoint bacon more times than I care to admit!

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is about programming related questions, your question is more of a user question.

You can't roll back a content editor. If you have versioning enabled for the page you have the content editor on, you might be lucky and can retrieve an earlier version. Otherwise you could only check the database for the content editor contents, but that will be a pretty tedious task finding it.